# MS Access not showing controls/fields/data in form

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I have a form that has a tab control with fields/textboxes/etc. referring to multiple tables for input. All my tables have one-one relationships. The main table primary key is P_ID. All other tables have their own primary keys and the P_ID fk. I am trying to find a way for Access to read the tables and populate my form accordingly. I really prefer not to use subforms. I am using MS Access as a front end to MYSQL Database via the ODBC connector.

Edit: I tried doing a SELECT t1.c1, t2.c1, ... etc FROM t1,t2....tn JOIN (t1,t2,...tn) ON (t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND tn...=tn...) I get a FROM syntax error.

Edit2: Based of katstevens' query structure I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM
T2 INNER JOIN
(T3 INNER JOIN
(T4 INNER JOIN
(T5 INNER JOIN
ON T5.ID = T1.ID)
ON T4.ID = T1.ID)
ON T3.ID = T1.ID)
ON T2.ID = T1.ID;
```

T1.ID is the primary key. All other tables (T2-T5).ID are fk. Each table has its own primary key(not listed). I am getting a syntax error in the FROM clause. All tables have one-to-one relationship to T1.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you edit your question to show some examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say hypothetically you have the following:

```
Table_1, primary key = P_ID
Table_2, foreign key = P_ID2
Table_3, foreign key = P_ID3
```

If they are all one-to-one (i.e. each record in table 1 only has one record in table 2), then I would wonder why tables 2 and 3 aren't using the same primary key. But irrespective, you would join them like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_3 INNER JOIN 
    (Table_1 INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.P_ID = Table_2.P_ID2) 
ON Table_1.P_ID = Table_3.P_ID3
```

I have deliberately called the foreign keys different names to illustrate what field needs to go where. This will return one single record for each instance of `P_ID`, with fields from all three tables in the single record.

The join syntax in your comment is incorrect. Each join can only be between **two tables**, and must name at least one pair of fields to compare to determine equality. You can nest as many as you like, but joins = poor performance if used improperly.

Comment: I have tried that. I tried doing a `SELECT t1.c1, t2.c1, ... etc` `FROM t1,t2....tn` `JOIN (t1,t2,...tn) ON (t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND tn...=tn...)`

I get a FROM syntax error.

Comment: How would I do multiple `INNER JOIN`s to the Table_Main (in this case your Table_1)? Also, I don't understand why there is a sub `INNER JOIN`. Do I keep adding sub `INNER JOIN` for every table I want to show records?

Comment: The join I have shown actually joins Table_2 and Table_3 to Table_1 - but they have to happen individually. I have nested it with brackets to make the syntax clear. First innermost join is execute (T1 and T2), then Table_3 is joined in, but if you see the condition at the end, Table_3 is actually joining to Table_1 as well. I suggest a bit of google research on joins will make it clearer